# How to know recyclerview visible items which exist another recyclerview? (Nested recyclerview impression)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have recyclerview. This recyclerview has view holder which has another recyclerview. Both recyclerview orientation is vertical. What I'd like to do is listen child recyclerview impression event. In other words, I'd like to listen child recyclerview items which are visible on the screen according to user scroll actions. How can I achieve this ? Any idea or thoughts
?

[image]